# Melt four (or more) dataframe columns into two rows

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-melt

I am trying to convert a `dataframe` of structure:

```
ID ID2 ID3 R_u L_u R_sd L_sd
1  F   G1   x   y   z    t
2  M   G2   x   y   z    t
```

into

```
ID ID2 ID3 Side u sd
1  F   G1   R    x z
1  F   G1   L    y t 
2  M   G2   R    x z
2  M   G2   L    y t
```

I used [`pandas.melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html) function

```
df_melt = df(id_vars=[('ID')], value_vars=['R_u', 'L_u'], 
                                  var_name='Side', value_name = 'u')
```

but I couldn't find a way for more than four or six number of columns simultaneously. I guess I can start with melt and then feed each row using `lambda` but I feel like I can do this automatically.

Any possible solution, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good use case for [`janitor`](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/)'s [`pivot_longer`](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.pivot.pivot_longer):

```
# pip install janitor
import janitor

out = df.pivot_longer(index="ID*", names_to=['Side', '.value'], names_sep='_',
                      sort_by_appearance=True # optional
                      )
```

Output:

```
   ID ID2 ID3 Side  u sd
0   1   F  G1    R  x  z
1   1   F  G1    L  y  t
2   2   M  G2    R  x  z
3   2   M  G2    L  y  t
```

With pure pandas, using reshaping and a MultiIndex:

```
cols = list(df.filter(like='ID'))

out = (df.set_index(cols)
         .pipe(lambda d: d.set_axis(d.columns.str.split('_', expand=True), axis=1))
         .rename_axis(columns=('Side', None))
         .stack(0).reset_index()
      )
```

Output:

```
   ID ID2 ID3 Side sd  u
0   1   F  G1    L  t  y
1   1   F  G1    R  z  x
2   2   M  G2    L  t  y
3   2   M  G2    R  z  x
```

Comment: @sammywemmy you always amaze me with `janitor`, this possibility wasn't clearly described in the docs. Thanks! :)

Comment: yea, `pivot_longer` has a number of features and conveniences ... not sure how to balance adding examples and not making it bloated ... open to PRs to help with that :)

Comment: Interesting, never used janitor before. It’s such a shame because melt is so easy to use

Answer (score 2):

Set the ID column as index then split and expand the remaining columns to convert to multiindex then stack the level 0 of multiindex to reshape

```
s = df.set_index('ID')
s.columns = s.columns.str.split('_', expand=True)
s = s.stack(0)
```

Alternative approach with `wide_to_long`

```
pd.wide_to_long(df, i='ID', j='Side', stubnames=['R', 'L'], sep='_', suffix='\w+').stack().unstack(-2)
```

Result

```
     sd  u
ID        
1  L  t  y
   R  z  x
2  L  t  y
   R  z  x
```

Another approach with `wide_to_long`, which might be a bit longer:

```py
temp = df.set_index(['ID','ID2','ID3'])
temp.columns = temp.columns.str.split("_").str[::-1].str.join("_")
(pd
.wide_to_long(
    temp.reset_index(), 
    i= temp.index.names, 
    j = 'Side', 
    stubnames = ['u', 'sd'], 
    sep='_', 
    suffix='.+')
.reset_index()
)

   ID ID2 ID3 Side  u sd
0   1   F  G1    R  x  z
1   1   F  G1    L  y  t
2   2   M  G2    R  x  z
3   2   M  G2    L  y  t
```

Comment: Ah this is a great solution but doesn't work if I have multiple ID columns -- I will edit my question

Comment: If you have multiple id columns then you can set the index accordingly.. for e.g.`df.set_index(['col1', 'col2', ...])`

Answer (score 1):

use pandasql its simple：

```
#%%
df1.sql("""
    select ID,ID2,ID3,'R' as Side,R_u as u,R_sd as sd from self
    union all select ID,ID2,ID3,'L' as Side,L_u as u,L_sd as sd from self
""").sort_values("ID")
```

out：

```
 ID ID2 ID3 Side  u sd
0   1   F  G1    R  x  z
2   1   F  G1    L  y  t
1   2   M  G2    R  x  z
3   2   M  G2    L  y  t
```

or pandas：

```
df11=df1.set_index(["ID","ID2","ID3"]).stack().reset_index(level=3)
df11.level_3.str.split("_",expand=True).set_axis(["Side","col1"],axis=1).assign(col2=df11.iloc[:,1]).reset_index().pivot(["ID","ID2","ID3","Side"],"col1","col2").reset_index(level=[1,2,3])
```

---

```
from pandasql import sqldf
sqldf("""
    select ID,ID2,ID3,'R' as Side,R_u as u,R_sd as sd from df1
    union all select ID,ID2,ID3,'L' as Side,L_u as u,L_sd as sd from df1
""",globals())
```

[image]

Comment: Your `pandasql` approach gives this error: `'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'sql'`.

Comment: The error is reported because I modified the pandas source code to encapsulate the sql method, if you need the original usage, please refer to the end of the answer @PaulS

Comment: Thanks for your answer, @G.G., but still getting errors: `ObjectNotExecutableError: Not an executable object: "\n    select ID,ID2,ID3,'R' as Side,R_u as u,R_sd as sd from df\n    union all select ID,ID2,ID3,'L' as Side,L_u as u,L_sd as sd from df\n"`.

Comment: it works on my pycharm ，look the picture.  maybe the reason is " , you can use """ """

Comment: Thanks again, @G.G. For some reason, every example I use with `sqldf` gives an error. Therefore, I think the problem is on my side.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution:

```
import re 

(df.filter(like='ID')
 .join(pd.concat(
     [df.filter(like=x).rename(lambda c: re.sub(r'^.*_', '', c), axis=1)
      .assign(Side = x) for x in ['R', 'L']])))
```

Output:

```
   ID ID2 ID3  u sd Side
0   1   F  G1  x  z    R
0   1   F  G1  y  t    L
1   2   M  G2  x  z    R
1   2   M  G2  y  t    L
```

---

Another possible solution, based on [`pandas.melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html) +  [`pandas.DataFrame.pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html#pandas.DataFrame.pivot):

```
ids = ['ID', 'ID2', 'ID3']
d = df.melt(ids)
(d.join(d['variable'].str.extract('(.*)_(.*)'))
 .rename({0: 'Side'}, axis=1)
 .pivot(index = ids + ['Side'], columns=[1], values='value')
 .reset_index().rename_axis(None, axis=1))
```

Output:

```
   ID ID2 ID3 Side sd  u
0   1   F  G1    L  t  y
1   1   F  G1    R  z  x
2   2   M  G2    L  t  y
3   2   M  G2    R  z  x
```